# How to seed a django model with foreign key and many to many fields at the same time?

Tags: python, django, database

i want to know the method of seeding for m2m and foreign key fields in a model of django automatically

i use django fixtures but it is all manual system. i would like to know to automated way to do the fill the database.I want to know is there any way to make it rather than fixtures in eaborative way.

Answer (score 0):

You an use django's loaddata command to populate initial data to models.

From django offical docs
As an example, though, here’s what a fixture for a Person model might look like in JSON:
create a json file and add to your app.

The following add data to person model in my app

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
  }
]
```

You can load data by calling **python manage.py loaddata** , where  is the name of the fixture file you’ve created

In case of m2m,
You can create 3 fixtures ( 3 json files )
2 for model eg  (student, course) and one for their association.
and run the loaddata for each of then.

or create a django management command which run all 3 of the loaddata command (in the order).

Note: If you have already data in your model, use python manage.py dumpdata, to create fixture files automatically.

[Refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/initial-data/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20load%20data%20by,and%20reloaded%20into%20the%20database.)

The other way is use database dump command to fill data in models.